# Flags on steroids

Tags: c#, iterator, enum

What is so bad about `[Flags]` enum? It does not support `IEnumerable<T>` anyhow, so to get one we need to use syntax like ([see](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307773/specify-optional-parameter-names-even-though-not-required)):

> ```
> new HashSet<WhatToInclude>(new []{ 
>     WhatToInclude.Cleaners, 
>     WhatToInclude.Managers}
> ```

Here is the helper class `Flag<T>` to discuss. We can use it this way:

> ```
> class Color : Flag<Color>
> {
>     public static readonly Color Red = new Color();
>     public static readonly Color Green = new Color();
>     public static readonly Color Yellow = new Color();
> }
> ```

Manipulation and testing:

> ```
> Color c = Color.None;
> c += Color.Yellow + Color.Red;
> c -= Color.Yellow + Color.Green;
>
> // it implements IEnumerable<T>
> bool t1 = c.Contains(Color.Red) // true
> bool t2 = c.Contains(Color.None) // always false
> ```

Refactoring of enumeration to classes is half way done here already :)

Library code:

```
abstract class Flag<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
    where T : Flag<T>, new()
{
    public static T None = new T() { Flags = new T[0] };

    protected Flag()
    {
        Flags = new[] { (T)this };
    }

    IEnumerable<T> Flags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Flags.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public static T operator+(Flag<T> left, Flag<T> right)
    {
        return new T()
        {
            Flags = left.Concat(right).Distinct().ToArray()
        };
    }

    public static T operator-(Flag<T> left, Flag<T> right)
    {
        return new T()
        {
            Flags = left.Except(right).ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

**Extra example**

> ```
> class FamilyMember : Flag<FamilyMember>
> {
>     public static readonly FamilyMember Me = new FamilyMember() { Name = "Dmitry" };
>     public static readonly FamilyMember Wife = new FamilyMember() { Name = "Julia" };
>     public static readonly FamilyMember Cat = new FamilyMember() { Name = "Willy" };
>     public static readonly FamilyMember All = Me + Wife + Cat;
>
>     public string Name { get; private set; }
> }
> ```

We can use it in a very simple way:

> ```
> foreach (var fm in FamilyMember.All - FamilyMember.Cat)
>             Console.WriteLine($"Hello {fm.Name}!");
> ```

It is much more than just an Enum.

Comment: Can you give some context as to why you think this is going to be useful? I'm struggling to see what the point of it is

Comment: Why would you want an `enum` to support `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Please see an example above.

Comment: Enums aren't "things" like objects. What you're asking is similar to asking whether or not you could add LINQ to floats or decimals. Yes, you *could* do it, but it doesn't make sense; there's no reason you couldn't create a static class with the utilities you need that would have the pleasant effect of not blowing up type safety

Comment: @DanPantry - Enums are countable, floats are not.  Enum are refactorable to classes which are definitely things. Sorry, I can not agree.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not going to say I'd use this, nor that I wouldn't.

I think it's a *clever*<sup>1</sup> use of generics, and turns C# enums into *something else* that could possibly be called `JavaIshEnum`; being an actual class, you significantly blur the line between classes and enums, but you also effectively *work around* the annoying absence of a generic type constraint in the C# compiler, that can constraint enum types.

Or do you?

```
public class Kaboom : Flag<SomeClass>
{
    ...
}
```

This derived type can be legally constructed... and shouldn't be allowed to. Of course, compile-time check is going to be hard (impossible?) - but your code is missing a *run-time* check.

I'd make the base constructor throw and forbid the creation of a non-enum `T`:

```
protected Flag()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Non-enum type is not a valid type argument.");
    }
    Flags = new[] { (T)this };
}
```

---

I don't like this:

> ```
> IEnumerable<T> Flags { get; set; }
> public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Flags.GetEnumerator();
> IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
> ```

You're only specifying access modifiers when you're overriding the default. I would have liked to see this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> Flags { get; set; }
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Flags.GetEnumerator();
private IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
```

And then raise the question, *why does `Flags` need to be an auto-property?* If it's `private`, wouldn't just the backing field be enough? I don't get the point of private properties.. I just don't.

I also don't like that you have `private` and `public` members intertwined. Regroup them.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> is that a good thing?</sub>

Comment: @mats-mug - Actually, T is not intended to be `enum`, and can not be  (see usage example above). The class is used like a enum syntactically  with extra features but is not a enum or compatible to it. `typeof(T).IsEnum == false`.

Comment: I prefer to do not type code which is not necessary to type. Default visibility has been chosen by Microsoft in a clever way :)

Comment: Then there should be a `class` type constraint, ...and you're twisting the meaning of `enum` beyond recognition. I wouldn't call it anything remotely related to an enum, unless your target audience is writing Java.

Comment: Well, there is a class constraint. Have a look at the code. Flag<T> is a class and T is a Flag<T> :)

Comment: Wow your code is even more confusing at second read than at first glance.

Comment: Sorry for using this term, but it has the same applicability as enum - just more features.

Comment: I prefer to use auto property here. It makes general sense. Someone can come and make your class member public because s/he needs it outside. Then you are stuck with that - you can not change from public field to public property without recompiling the client code. It is always possible to change auto property to backed up property if necessary.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree then. A mutable `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't look like something I'd cheerfully expose. If the accessibility needs to change, there's a design flaw IMO. But don't mind me, I'm just a mug.

Comment: @mats-mug Yep, I would also fight for keeping this one private for sure. It is just a reasonable default approach to define private properties, not fields, if we can choose I think. Framework Design Guidelines says that .NET authors consider field/property distinction as a serious design flaw now, they would prefer to just have properties.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take your example to a silly extreme to illustrate a point:

```
foreach (var f in FamilyMember.All - FamilyMember.Cat)
{
    foreach (var f1 in f)
    {
        foreach (var f2 in f1)
        {
            foreach (var f3 in f2)
            {
                foreach (var f4 in f3)
                {
                    foreach (var f5 in f4)
                    {
                        foreach (var f6 in f5)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {f6.Name}!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If all of the `Flag<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>` how do I know when to stop enumerating? I think it's a potentially confusing API design.

There's also no way to go back to the property name as far as I can tell - in your colour example how do I know what colours are in it?

I don't see what all of this buys you to be completely honest.

Comment: It is always flat (1 level collection), so it is not so bad. You can check varable c of type Color this way: "c == Color.Red" or "c.Contains(Color.Red)" or "c.Any(cc => cc == Color.Red)", etc.

Comment: @DmitryNogin - you know that  but your **code doesn't communicate** it. What about getting the label? E.g. in your first test, how do I know which colours are in the final thing?

Comment: It is no different from usual Enum. You have no "label" there, so it is the same way here. You have all the power of LINQ for testing.

Comment: @DmitryNogin - so all of this extra power results in nearly the exact same code I would have typed anyway? Why is `x.Contains()` better that `Enum.HasFlag()`?

Comment: In my experience I use class hierarchies more often than enums. At least to say that I refactor enum to class hierarchy more often then in the opposite direction. I really appreciate possibility to have some state/strategies associated with "enum members" and having LINQ projecting/processing over them makes my day from time to time :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin - Completely agree - I have very few enums in any of my codebases. I have just never needed to rengineer `Flags`. I don't see how what you have is anything other than a collection.

Comment: Flags behavior are different from the one of collection. You can not create element at run-time or add the same thing twice or more. It is definitely a dedicated stereotype.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Statefulness doesn't belong in enums. Enums are - literally - *enumerations* of values. Those enumerations are 1) fixed 2) known at compile time and 3) *just* values with names associated with them. It sounds like what you want is a Java enum in C# - that's not going to do. The two concepts simply are not comparable.

Comment: There is nothing bad in Java enums themselves or using them in C#. Why do you think that we can not borrow it as many other things?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would not want to use any "magic enum" class, simply because in the end of the day it is not enum. And therefore any code, which takes `Enum` as an argument, fetches an attribute or calls `GetType().IsEnum` won't work for this class. In rare cases where `HasFlag` method is not enough, and you actually need to enumerate flags, some static/extension method (say, `ToEnumerable`) should do a better job.

Answer (score 3):

> What is so bad about [Flags] enum? It does not support IEnumerable ...

You can iterate flagged enums with the following extension method:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> AsEnumerable<TEnum>(this TEnum flaggedEnum)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enumerated type");

        Enum flaggs = flaggedEnum as Enum;
        foreach (TEnum val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        {
            if (flaggs.HasFlag(val as Enum))
                yield return val;
        }
    }
}
```

Using that extension, the flagged enum

```
[Flags]
public enum FamilyMember
{
    Me = 1,
    Wife  = 2,
    Cat = 4,
    All = 7
}
```

can be iterated via:

```
// foreach (var value in (FamilyMember.Me | FamilyMember.Wife).AsEnumerable()) or
foreach (var value in (FamilyMember.All ^ FamilyMember.Cat).AsEnumerable())
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {value}!");
// Output:
// Hello Me!
// Hello Wife!
```

Comment: Thanks. I would call this method `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Yes, `AsEnumerable` sounds better better. Thanks.